# How can I group by month without losing the order by year?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Trying to sort data for display in a graph by the year and the month category. Sorting first by year and then by month goes great, but then as soon as I try to group each item together based on month, the year sorting goes out the window.

Let's say that I have an array of objects as follows

```
const arr = [
        {month: 1, year: 2021},
        {month: 2, year: 2021},
        {month: 3, year: 2021},
        {month: 3, year: 2021},
        {month: 4, year: 2021},
        {month: 9, year: 2020},
        {month: 9, year: 2020},
        {month: 10, year: 2020},
        {month: 11, year: 2020},
        {month: 12, year: 2020},
        {month: 12, year: 2020},
      ];
```

I then sort based on year and then month so I get this resulting arr:

```
[
  {month: 9, year: 2020},
  {month: 9, year: 2020},
  {month: 10, year: 2020},
  {month: 11, year: 2020},
  {month: 12, year: 2020},
  {month: 12, year: 2020},
  {month: 1, year: 2021},
  {month: 2, year: 2021},
  {month: 3, year: 2021},
  {month: 3, year: 2021},
  {month: 4, year: 2021}
]
```

How can I then group the objects into an array of each month while not losing this order? Trying to end up with something like the following Object. Every time I try to group by month it ends up sorting it based on month and so Month: 1 ends up coming first which screws up the graph.

```
const groupedUp = {
  9: [{month: 9, year: 2020},{month: 9, year: 2020}],
  10: [{month: 10, year: 2020}],
  11: [{month: 11, year: 2020}],
  12: [{month: 12, year: 2020}, {month: 12, year: 2020}],
  1: [{month: 1, year: 2021}],
  2: [{month: 2, year: 2021}],
  3: [{month: 3, year: 2021},{month: 3, year: 2021}],
  4: [{month: 4, year: 2021}]
}
```

Comment: You have limited control over the order of object properties. Numbered properties are always in numeric order, other properties are in order of creation. Use an array if you want to control the order.

Comment: So create the object with the grouping you want, use `Object.entries()` to convert it to an array of arrays, then rotate the elements of the array to get month 9 first.

Answer (score 2):

In an object, numeric properties are always sorted in ascending order. You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead to maintain insertion order when grouping.

```js
let sorted = [
  {month: 9, year: 2020},
  {month: 9, year: 2020},
  {month: 10, year: 2020},
  {month: 11, year: 2020},
  {month: 12, year: 2020},
  {month: 12, year: 2020},
  {month: 1, year: 2021},
  {month: 2, year: 2021},
  {month: 3, year: 2021},
  {month: 3, year: 2021},
  {month: 4, year: 2021}
];
let res = sorted.reduce((map, curr) => {
  if (!map.has(curr.month)) map.set(curr.month, []);
  map.get(curr.month).push(curr);
  return map;
}, new Map);
res.forEach((v, k) => console.log(k, '=', JSON.stringify(v)));
```